# Persistent session in ASP.Net core

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to make the session persistent in ASP.Net Core? So far I can only find information about cookie expiration connected to ASP.Net Identity (which I am not using), or session idle timeout (which does not persist after the user closes the browser).

Where do I find options to make the session persistent?

Comment: You want the session to persist after you close down the browser?

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien, yes, that is the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Session is built on top of `IDistributedCache` so I guess you are looking for its persistent implementation (Redis, SQL Server etc.).
[Working with a distributed cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed).

Comment: I know this article is very old, but I have a weird problem, I use SQL for my sessions with expires in 365 days in a project with .net 6, the problem is everything is alright on my laptop with chrome and firefox browser, but in my android mobile, sessions lost every few hours, any solution?