# IsPersistent not working PasswordSignInAsync Identity asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I use dotnet core 5 and Identity for authorization in my website. I have a custom class `User` for my Identity.

This is my ConfigureServices:

```cs
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(e =>
                {
                    e.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    e.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    e.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    e.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    e.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    e.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 2;
                    e.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
                    e.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
                    e.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

and in my Configure I have:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This is my SignIn Controller:

```cs
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost("/Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result =
                    await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Usename or password");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

But Even if `Model.RememberMe` is true, the SignIn is not persistent and User Needs to signin every 20 minutes.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: in addition to the answer below, please check if your data protection keys are the same, this is especially important if the application is hosted on multiple instances. (running inside docker containers for example), i had  a problem with this a while ago and it took me some time to figure this out

Comment: I am not using DataProtection

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `ExpireTimeSpan` of cookie.Here is a sample to set expiretime to 1 day:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
});
```

Comment: I want to give user the choice to have a persistant session or not

Comment: You can refer  to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370722/persistent-session-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: You mean I shouldn't use cookies for authentication?

Comment: There isn't something like IsPersistent for cookie.So you can set ExpireTimeSpan to a very long time if you  want to use cookie authentication.

Comment: Then what is the point of IsPersistent in Identity?