# .NET core application randomly logouts users

Tags: iis, .net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

We've been developing an app on a test server without any single problem occuring during the whole development time. After moving it to different production server several problems with built in core identity started to occur.

When user logs in, the browser successfully stores identity token and the user can navigate all pages, however after navigating few times the app suddenly logs user out, the token is still saved in browser history however it seems to be not valid anymore. The time this happens is completely random, sometimes after navigating once, sometimes after few navigations/refreshes

Comment: Take a look here and look also at the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67366526/7968203

Comment: Found  a solution there, thank you

Comment: your welcome close the question ^^ if you have your answer ;)